# How to block url that customer type on browser in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have created a website, And I don't to allowed customer to type link in browser. 
I just want to allow customer click link on the website only.

please provide me a solution !!!

thank for help !!!

Answer (score 1):

use token for in hyperlinks . deny if token wont match to value in session.

try the following:

1. in controller check if session['token'] is set,
   if not  set session['token'] to a rendom value.
2. if token not set or won't match to $_GET['token'] variable redirect to error page.
3. if token match to get variable (ie. $_GET['token']) then , pass that value to view.

i don't recomend this because doing this might affect the browser cache.

Controller constructor

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('session');

  if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))
  {
    $_SESSION['token'] = rand();
  }

  if((!$this->input->get('token')) || ($this->input->get('token') != $_SESSION['token']))
  {
    redirect('error_page');
  }

  // to pass to vew
  $data['token'] = $_SESSION['token'];
  $this->load->view('view_page',$data);
}
```

in view_page.php (view) replace links like this

```
<a href="#link?token=<?php echo $token?>">Gallery link</a>
```